# How NOT to display value 0 in a coord_polar using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a coord_polar plot without display 0,0% values. I've tried this but I have a error (Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): x, y, label, fill)

```
a <- c("A", "B", "C")
b <- c(0, 20, 40)
c<- data.frame(a,b)
c$pct <- c$b/sum(c$b) #labels positions

p_c <- ggplot(c, aes(x=0.5, y=b, fill=a)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="white", width=1) +
  coord_polar(theta='y') +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),                      
    axis.text.x=element_blank())+
  geom_text(data=subset(c,b >0.05),aes(x=1.2, y=cumsum(c$b) - c$b/2,
            label=percent(c$pct)))+
 labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)

 p_c
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not `subset` your data. Use `ifelse`:

```
ggplot(c, aes(x=0.5, y=b, fill=a)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", color="white", width=1) +
coord_polar(theta='y') +
theme_bw()+
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),                      
      axis.text.x=element_blank())+
geom_text(data=c,aes(x=1.2, y=cumsum(c$b) - c$b/2,
                                     label=ifelse(b>0.5,percent(c$pct),"")))+
labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```